# why Efail CFB malleability gadget is different from CFB mode decryption?

Tags: pgp

Really, I could not understand why the decryption process of CFB malleability gadget takes the next cipher block while PGP uses the previous block as shown in the equations in the attached image[image], I read Efail attack paper but I could not understand how it works? Could someone clarify it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both schemes present in your image represent the same thing. Only the indexing of *C<sub>i</sub>* differ by 1. It all depends on what you consider to be your "first block":

- In the first, you decrypt by manipulating the previous block and the current block. This means your decryption process start with *C<sub>-1</sub>* and *C<sub>0</sub>* to recover *P<sub>0</sub>*. Here, *C<sub>-1</sub> = IV*
- In the other, you decrypt by manipulating the current block and the next. So *P<sub>0</sub> = Enc(C<sub>0</sub>) XOR C<sub>1</sub>*, meaning *C<sub>0</sub> = IV*.

---

**Clarification:**

CFB malleability gadget does not modify the decryption process in any way. The only trick is to modify the ciphertext before decryption.

You seem to have trouble with the notation and the block indexing, so here is a little example of how the CFB gadget would be used. In this example, C<sub>0</sub> is the first block of *encrypted* data, the IV is considered apart (whereas C<sub>0</sub> is the IV if we follow Efail notation, hence the shift in the index you may notice in my figure).

[image]

To make it clear, keeping the same notation as in my figure, CFB decryption would go as follow:

- P<sub>0</sub> = Enc(IV) xor C<sub>0</sub>
- P<sub>1</sub> = Enc(C<sub>0</sub>) xor C<sub>1</sub>
- P<sub>2</sub> = Enc(C<sub>1</sub>) xor C<sub>2</sub>
- ...
- P<sub>i</sub> = Enc(C<sub>i-1</sub>) xor C<sub>i</sub>
- P<sub>i+1</sub> = Enc(C<sub>i</sub>) xor C<sub>i+1</sub>
- ...

That is how CFB decryption works, whether or not you are using it as a gadget.

Comment: That means the injection of  the malleability gadget blocks in PGP ciphertext will work right at decryption process, although PGP CFB mode encrypts the previous block XORed with the current block to get the plaintext for example P2 = Ek(C1) ⊕ C2, while  CFB malleability gadget encrypts the current block XORed with the next block to get the plaintext for example P2 = Ek(C2) ⊕ C3. I am really still confused.

Comment: @Sam2050 I'm not sure to get what you are struggling with, but the fact you give two different operation for CFB decryption in the same sentence makes me think you miss something. I added some clarification to my answer as long with a example to illustrate the process.

Comment: @Sam2050 To be clear, the index difference between the two figures in your original post stem from the fact that one notation includes the IV in the Ci, whereas the other don't.

Comment: Thank you very much  Faulst, I got it, Efail team used C0 instead of  IV. And the decryption process and block sequences are the same as OpenPGP standard.